# Edit subject of received email in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

As I was examining the limitation of Outlook 2010's conversation view that strictly groups by subject line, I thought, since I cannot change the mechanism, could I change the subject line of received emails so I could manually split things into multiple conversations as the occasion warrants?

My experiment began thusly:

1. Open mail item.
2. Edit subject line.
3. Select **Save** -- result:

   "Your changes cannot be saved because you don't have permission to modify some or all of the items in this folder. Do you want to save a copy of this item in the default folder for the item?"
4. Answer "Yes" -- result:

   Microsoft Outlook has encountered a problem and needs to close.

This error is 100% reproducible. Is there a workaround for this error? And where the heck is the "default folder for the item" ?

Comment: I don't have an answer as I'm not using 2010,  but I can tell you that under Outlook 2007 I can do what you suggest, and it lets me save the message with the new subject without a prompt (and it saves to the Inbox, where I opened the mail from).  Where were the test emails you used located? Are they in your personal Inbox, or someplace like a separate, or public, folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might answer your question.  Taken from [This forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/outlook/thread/101b5c14-a9d7-425a-b3fd-c937591ce76e)

It's ALWAYS possible and easy to edit the SUBJECT. But even when you open the message, you can choose for Action -> Edit Message and also adjust the content. Just before replying/forwarding. Or leave it (adjusted) as it is in you mailbox.

Often I choose the Edit Message when replying to Plain Text messages (or these dreaded RTF ones). I open the message, change it into HTML, save it and reply or forward it. And sometimes I choose the subject because the original sender used a wrong subject or replied to a a wrong message.

Comment: Under Message tab > Move > Actions the "Edit Message" choice is greyed out for me. Perhaps there is something with the enterprise configuration that controls that capability...?

Comment: I tried a different message; this one had "Edit Message" enabled and allowed me to save without incident. Sigh...

Comment: Are you talking about "secure" emails? Emails that do NOT allow printing or fowarding?

Comment: No, not secure emails.